Prevent scrolling page after animate scrollTop on mobile
I'm trying to do targeted scrolling within a specific block on a page from its inner element to top of next\prev element.
Scripts:
jquery-2.2.0.min.js
jquery.mobile.min.js

Html:
<div class="someblock" style="height:100px;">n</div>
<div class="someblock" style="height:100px;">n</div>
<div class="someblock" style="height:100px;">n</div>


<div class="target" style="height:600px;">
    <div class="targetblock" style="height:200px;">1</div>
    <div class="targetblock" style="height:200px;">2</div>
    <div class="targetblock" style="height:200px;">3</div>
</div>

<div class="someblock" style="height:100px;">n</div>
<div class="someblock" style="height:100px;">n</div>
<div class="someblock" style="height:100px;">n</div>

I check touch event inside target div
document.addEventListener("touchend", scroll);

var scroll = function (){
    //some code we are inside target div
    .......
    
    if(weAreInside){
        //so we finish scrolling to the top of some element
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$_targetblock.eq(element).offset().top},300);
        scrolled = true;
    }
}

Solve issue of scrolling from outside of the target div
var scrolled = false;

document.addEventListener("scrollend", scrolledend);

var scrolledend = function (){
    if(scrolled==false){
        scroll();
    }
};

All it works, but...
if touchmove is fast, so i have some page scrolling after animate function, and this breaks logic of scrolling from top to top of inner elements of target div.
I'm trying to find a way to stop "scrolling after" effect inside target div.
I think i don't need any ready code, but some ideas, maybe some events to change logic or catch this issue in a moment.
